# Basic Javascript String Manipulation

Tags: javascript, string

Hello there everyone,

I've been trying to figure out how to create a function that takes any input and adds spaces to it before returning it. For example. The function would change "hello" into "h e l l o"
When I perform the task -not- as a function, it seems to work okay. I previously had some good feedback about using the split() and join() functions and that seems to get the desired effect.

It just doesn't seem to be working as a function. Here is the code that I have come up with so far:

```
function sStr(aString)
{   
    var mySplitResult = aString.split("").join(" ");
    return mySplitResult;  
}
window.alert(sStr(test));
```

I would really appreciate any help with this as I'm racking my brains trying to learn this stuff. I can see that I still have a long way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around `test` like :

```
alert(sStr("test"));
```

Comment: Wow. now I feel like a fool. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, test is not a string, but a variable. Strings need to be inserted in quotes or double quotes.

```
function sStr(aString)
{   
    return aString.split("").join(" ");
}
window.alert(sStr('test'));
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDbyU/2/).

Comment: Again - I feel like a bit of a ninny - thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It works, just add quotes around *test*:

```
function sStr(aString)
{   
    var mySplitResult = aString.split("").join(" ");
    return mySplitResult;  
}
window.alert(sStr("test"));
```

Comment: Wow. now I feel like a fool. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks your function works beautifully. In this line:

```
window.alert(sStr(test));
```

Is `test` a variable, or did you mean to provide a string:

```
window.alert(sStr('test'));
```

While we're at it, you may want to make your function handle the cases where the (1) parameter is undefined or null and (2) the parameter is not a string (e.g.: numbers):

```
function sStr(aString)
{   
    if(!aString)
    {
        return "";
    }

    var mySplitResult = aString.toString().split("").join(" ");
    return mySplitResult;  
}
```